# Can't get the state after signing in with fluxor an Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, reducers, fluxor

I want to implement state management into an application Blazor assembly, so I added Fluxor as library.

I've created an abstract root state which contain the shared propreties:

```
public abstract class RootState
{
    public RootState(bool isLoading, string currentErrorMessage)
        => (IsLoading, CurrentErrorMessage) = (isLoading, currentErrorMessage);

    public bool IsLoading { get; }
    public string CurrentErrorMessage { get; }

    public bool HasCurrentErrors => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CurrentErrorMessage);

}
```

Then, I created the Login State which inherits from Rootstate:

```
 public class LoginState : RootState
{
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    public LoginResponseDto UserData { get; set; }
    public LoginState(bool isLoading, string currentErrorMessage, bool isAuthenticated, LoginResponseDto userData)
        :base(isLoading, currentErrorMessage)
    {
        IsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
        UserData = userData;
    }
}
```

After that, I created the feature class :

```
public class LoginFeature : Feature<LoginState>
{
    public override string GetName() => nameof(LoginState);

    protected override LoginState GetInitialState()
        => new LoginState(false, null, false, null);
}
```

Then the actions:

```
public class LoginAction
{
    public LoginDto LoginDto { get; }
    public LoginAction(LoginDto LoginDto)
    {
        this.LoginDto = LoginDto;
    }
}

public class LoginAccessFailure : FailureAction
{
    public LoginAccessFailure(string errorMessage)
        :base(errorMessage)
    {

    }
}

public abstract class FailureAction
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; }

    protected FailureAction(string errorMessage) => ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
}
```

After that I created the Reducer and Effect:

```
public class LoginReducer
{
    [ReducerMethod]
    public static LoginState ReduceLoginAction(LoginState state, LoginAction action)
        => new LoginState(true, null, false, state.UserData);

    [ReducerMethod]
    public static LoginState ReduceLoginSuccessAction(LoginState state, LoginActionSuccess action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("State from Reducer", action);
        var result = new LoginState(false, null, action.IsAuthenticated, action.UserData);
        Console.WriteLine("Result from Reducer", result);

        return result;
    }

    [ReducerMethod]
    public static LoginState ReduceLoginFailureAction(LoginState state, LoginAccessFailure action)
        => new LoginState(false, action.ErrorMessage, false, null);
}
```

Effect:

```
 public class LoginEffect : Effect<LoginAction>
{
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

    public LoginEffect(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

    public  override  async Task HandleAsync(LoginAction action, IDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        try
        {
            var loginResponse = await _accountService.Login(action.LoginDto);

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            dispatcher.Dispatch(new LoginActionSuccess(loginResponse, true));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            dispatcher.Dispatch(new LoginAccessFailure(e.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to call the dispatcher with this instruction `dispatcher.Dispatch(new LoginAction(new LoginDto { Email = "test@email.com", Password = "test" }));` I've got the result in the DevTools but there is not data in `IState<LoginState>` so I can't access to the state.
There is any error on my code please ?

Comment: Does your blazor component inherit from FluxorComponent? If not it won't automatically call StateHasChanged().

Answer (score 1):

Things to check

1. You have `[Inject]` before your `private IMyState<T> MyState { get; set; }`
2. You have a `<StoreInitializer/>` component in your main app component.
3. Your component descends from `FluxorComponent` or you manually subscribe to `MyState.StateChanged` and call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`